# Setup Vim to cut fold line after 80 characters

Tags: vim, folding, text-width

In my `.vimrc` file I have `textwidth=80` and a white line indicating 80 characters per line limit. Now, as I am also using folds, is there any way to cut fold lines to 80 characters.

Right now a fragment of C file in my setup looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The display of folded lines can be customized by the `foldtext` setting. In your case you likely want to restrict the width of the text so you would need to write a custom function that does this. As an example consider my [CustomFoldText() function](https://github.com/chrisbra/vim_dotfiles/blob/a1a106081884647922395fe4512aa8fcc887d64c/plugin/CustomFoldText.vim) (simply specify a maximum width via the `g:custom_foldtext_max_width` variable.)